# React not overwriting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, flux

I'm usign setState to change the state of my component.

It works fine until i need to delete an element from the state.

Let's pretend i have this on my store:

```
{
    0: {name: foo},
    1: {name: bar}
}
```

If I add another element, it works just fine:

```
store[2] = {name: hohoho};
setState(store, console.log(this.state));
```

With the code above, I end up with the expected state:

```
{
    0: {name: foo},
    1: {name: bar},
    2: {name: hohoho},
}
```

But if I delete one of the elements from the store and change the state again, it doesn't delete from the state:

```
delete store[2]
```

If I console.log(store), I get:

```
{
    0: {name: foo},
    1: {name: bar}
}
```

then:

```
setState(store, console.log(this.state))
```

gives me:

```
{
    0: {name: foo},
    1: {name: bar},
    2: {name: hohoho},
}
```

But stranger than this, is if I add another element to the store, and set the state after:

```
store[3] = {name: heyheyhey};
setState(store, console.log(this.state));
```

I end up with the following state:

```
{
    0: {name: foo},
    1: {name: bar},
    2: {name: hohoho},
    3: {name: heyheyhey}
}
```

Even if console.log(store) gives me the following:

```
{
    0: {name: foo},
    1: {name: bar},
    3: {name: heyheyhey}
}
```

Can someone please help me understand whats going on?

**EDIT**

Since some comments said delete might be the problem, i changed the way I'm deleting from my store:

```
var temp = {};
for (var x in store) {
    if (x != id) {
        temp[x] = store[x];
    }
}
store= temp;
```

But I'm still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Every time produce a new object instead of mutating state object directly

Comment: What do you mean by producing a new object? Can you elaborate?

Comment: That's because `delete` doesn't free up memory like you think it does.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: What is in the `store` variable? Does it reference the same object as state? Does something like `const nextStore = Object.assign({}, store); delete nextStore[2]; setState(nextStore);` resolve your issue? If so, then likely you mutate the same object.

Comment: BTW if you need to make changes to the state depending on its value, it better to do it this way: `this.setState(currentState => { const nextState = Object.assign({}, currentState); ...do changes in nextState...; return nextState;  })`

Comment: Please post full code of the component and store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question like I mentioned in my comment. `Delete` doesn't free up memory like the key word makes you think it does.

According to [MDN Delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

> Unlike what common belief suggests, the delete operator has nothing to do with directly freeing memory. Memory management is done indirectly via breaking references

So all you have to do is replace it with a new object instead of modifying the old one.

Edit:

Try something like this

```
cloneObject(obj) {
        if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
        var copy = obj.constructor();
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                copy[attr] = obj[attr];
            }
        }
        return copy;
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. Updated the answer with the updated code.

Comment: @RafaelAntunes just setting the value with `=` doesn't copy over a new copy of the object. That's still by reference.

Comment: It did not work either. I resolved it by setting the the state directly before using setState.

Comment: @RafaelAntunes don't mutate state directly. Only setState should be used to update the state. See my answer with assigning `undefiend` to the key you want to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the second `setState` param mistakenly.. 
You should be aware that:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

and `setState`'s second parameter is the callback:

> In addition, you can supply an optional callback function that is executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.
>   So your callback should be something like:

```
setState(store, (newState) => console.log(newState);
```

or the short version of it:

```
setState(store, console.log)
```

Otherwise you'd just be logging current class state and returning `undefined` as the second param (callback)

Comment: If you read the part that when i add another element, i have another element added without the previous element being deleted.

Comment: You should read my answer again, you are using setState the wrong way. The param forwarded to the callback is your final state. You are calling `console.log` even before you are setting the state....

Answer (score 0):

You might use `undefined` instead of delete:

```
const changes = [
  {
    title: 'add 2',
    update: state => Object.assign({}, state, { 2: { name: 'hohoho' } }),
  },
  {
    title: 'remove 2',
    update: state => Object.assign({}, state, { 2: undefined }),
  },
  {
    title: 'add 3',
    update: state => Object.assign({}, state, { 3: { name: 'heyheyhey' } }),
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      0: { name: 'foo' },
      1: { name: 'bar' },
    };
  }

  update(step) {
    this.setState(changes[step].update);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(this.update.bind(this, 0), 2000);
    setTimeout(this.update.bind(this, 1), 4000);
    setTimeout(this.update.bind(this, 2), 6000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    );
  }
}
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/jprogd/062z1kqd/2/

BTW When you do `this.setState({ a: something })` you don't actually set the whole state exactly to `{ a: something }` but update only certain properties (in this particular case only `a` property will be updated).